# JQuery Modal Dialog form post-back issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jquery modal dialog box to accept information from the user (as in a fillable form).

My modal form is displayed by the click of an input button:-

```
<button id="create-user" type="button">Please Check-in</button>
```

I must point out that the reason I have this input button as type="button" rather than the default of "submit" is because, If I leave it to default, there is a postback and the modal popup disappears (which I do not want for obvious reasons).

The modal-form looks as follows:-

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckInSystem._Default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/jscript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/jscript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/ProgramFiles/Popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to the Check-In Kiosk!
    </h2>
    <div style="margin-top: 40px">
    </div>
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="ActiveCheckIn" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999"
            BorderStyle="Outset" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="Black" 

            onrowcancelingedit="ActiveCheckIn_RowCancelingEdit" 
            onrowediting="ActiveCheckIn_RowEditing" 
            onrowupdating="ActiveCheckIn_RowUpdating" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"  />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 40px">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
    </div>
    <h2 style="margin-left: 20px">
        New Check-In?
    </h2>
       <button id="create-user" type="button" style="margin-left: 20%">
        Click Here!</button>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="New Visitor Check-in:">
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <p>
            * All form fields are required.</p>
        <div class="formContainer">
            <div class="row">
                <b>Visitor:</b>
                <input id="visitor" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 60px" required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <b>Type of Visit:</b>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="TypeOfVisitDesc" runat="server" DataValueField="TypeOfVisitKey"
                    DataTextField="TypeOfVisitDesc" CssClass="ddlist" DataSourceID="TypeOfVisitDataSrc">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="TypeOfVisitDataSrc" runat="server" ContextTypeName="CheckInSystem.CheckInSystemDataContext"
                    EntityTypeName="" TableName="TypeOfVisits">
                </asp:LinqDataSource>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <b>Visitee:</b>
                <input id="visitee" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 59px" required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <b>Arrival:</b>
                <input id="arrival" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 59px" required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <b>Departure:</b>
                <input id="departure" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 33px" required="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" runat="server" value="Check-In" class="myButton" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="statusMessage">
        <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Inside the modal popup there are several fields and at the end is a submit button:-

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" runat="server" value="Check-In" class="myButton"/>
```

My JS file for the jquery dialog box is as follows:-

```
   $(function () {
    var form;

    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 50
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        height: 455,
        width: 796,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            Cancel: function () {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
        alert("you have submitted the form!");
    });
});
```

The issue I am facing currently, is that because I have had to disable the first button ("create-user") from doing a postback...the submit button inside my modal popup is also not doing a postback...which means, the mechanism by which I collect the user data on the C# side of things is not being traversed:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            { Allow_CheckIn(); }
        }

 private void Allow_CheckIn()
        {
            using (CheckInSystemDataContext objDataContext = new CheckInSystemDataContext())
            {
                Checkin newCheckIn = new Checkin();
                newCheckIn.VisitorName = visitor.Value.ToString();
                newCheckIn.TypeOfVisitKey = Convert.ToInt32(TypeOfVisitDesc.SelectedValue);
                newCheckIn.VisiteeName = visitee.Value.ToString();
                newCheckIn.Arrival = Convert.ToDateTime(arrival.Value);
                newCheckIn.Departure = Convert.ToDateTime(departure.Value);

                objDataContext.CheckIns.InsertOnSubmit(newCheckIn);
                objDataContext.SubmitChanges();

                Status.Text = "Check-In successful!";
                Status.CssClass = "success";

                Bind_gvw_CheckIn();
            }
        }
```

However, I cannot make the first button a submit type... any suggestions what I can do, so that my Allow_CheckIn() is traversed after the data is inserted in the modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your issue has nothing to do with the 'create-user' button.  That is just a button that opens the modal window. You have done nothing to "disable the first button" as you have described.

Most likely your issue is that the form in the modal dialog isn't actually a form. There is no form tag with an action attribute to define what will happen when your submit button is clicked.

I'd suggest you check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) explanation on form actions.

check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TZ1vMcPoGvHTXecCwZwN?p=preview) that shows your submit action works if you add a form tag

```
plunker
```

Comment: by changing type= "button", I have stopped the postback.. believe me because I tested that part out... If I have type=submit, there is postback and my modal popup shows up and then disappears immediately.

Comment: also, when I had all the attributes that I have put inside the modal popup, outside of the popup div, then submit functionality worked with the same group of attributes and the single submit button.

Comment: even the simple required="true" functionality doesn't trigger in the modal popup.

Comment: check this sample https://plnkr.co/edit/TZ1vMcPoGvHTXecCwZwN?p=preview you can see that if you add the form tag it works. fill out the form in the modal and click the submit button. you should see an alert confirming that you have indeed submitted the form

Comment: Hey thanks for the example... I posted my code on plnkr and it works.. but doesn't work in Visual studio....https://plnkr.co/edit/uUWZc9PNSABQ9mpcwti9?p=preview

Maybe because I have an aspx page and not an html page?

Comment: you'd have to post your aspx markup and code behind file in order for me to say for sure. could have some other code interferring with form submissions